# Sql query to Check if any of columns in a XML row has value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlxml

I have below `XML`. I need to check if any of column in this row has a value or not.

```
<row>
    <Row></Row>
    <TaskName></TaskName>
    <TaskType>someFooValue</TaskType>
    <PlanDate></PlanDate>
    <ForecastDate></ForecastDate>
    <Status></Status>
    <AssignedTo></AssignedTo>
    <Predecessors></Predecessors>
    <SortOrder></SortOrder>
    <Duration></Duration>
    <PerComplete></PerComplete>
    <PlannedEndDate></PlannedEndDate>
    <ForecastEndDate></ForecastEndDate>
</row>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select @data.exist('row/*[text()]')
```

Will return `1` if there're some non-empty value.

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26049)</kbd>**